# Struct pointer and its pointer attribute issue

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Has this code undefined behaviour which means for s is mandatory to allocate memory or is ok this way ?
PS: what is the difference between

```
 struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(struct X));
      and
    struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(x)); 
    and 
    struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof *x);
```

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct X 
{
    int x;
    char* s;
};
int main()
{  
    struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(struct X));
    x->x = 10;
    // x->s = (char*)malloc(10);
    // memcpy...
    x->s = "something";
    printf("is ok?");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first one is correct as that one allocates the correct number of bytes to hold the structure.  The other two just allocates memory that is the size of a pointer: Either 4 or 8 bytes.  You don't really need `(struct X*)` on the malloc as the result is compatible with all pointer types.  Although it will work (and is a style issue), the conventional way to declare a pointer to a struct is `struct X x*`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than throw my own interpretation at you i felt it would be more helpful to share a link that might clarify what you are aiming to achieve:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-vs-malloc-and-free-vs-delete-in-c/

When you create a pointer i see that you have added the pointer to your char* variable / struct, but when calling them the use of the ampersand & is used as a reference to the address in the memory.

But not applied quite right using the int variable when declaring it no '*' and then referencing the location using '&'.

Comment: Maybe the basic of pointers and strings would be more useful here, no ?

Comment: This did cross my mind too, so yes very likely.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. Since `s` is part of the `struct`, allocating memory for the struct allocates memory for `s`. I would strongly suggest changing the type of `s` to be a `const` pointer, since it points to a literal which, because it's a type of constant, cannot be modified.

You cannot do `s[0]='n';` after this. You did not allocate any space to hold any string other than the unmodifiable literal `"something"`.

Comment: It seems to me that you should elaborate a little on static string versus dynamic allocation  of the strings, as the provided code may not be intended to deal with const string. Explain for example that a char pointer is at first a pointer and can then point anything (static strings in the program text section, dynamic allocation, string address in a ROM, etc.). Thus, assign a static string to `s` is fine but implies there should be no more string manipulation from `s` except if the static assignment was meant to "allocate" static space, etc.